# Re-download nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am working with a nuget feed where they sometimes change the package but they don't change the version number.

This means I often want a code change but Visual Studio doesn't show it as an update available.

I have many packages in several projects referenced.  What is quickest way to re-download all packages?

I have tried this command:

> Update-Package -reinstall

But it doesn't seem to force it to re-download the package as I am not getting new code.

How do I delete existing packages and force it to re-download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out way to do it is this command:

> dotnet nuget locals all -c

Then restart VS and rebuild